# How To Destroy Instantiated GameObjects Using A Coroutine?

Tags: unity

So I am making a Super Mario Bros. Clone and I am in the process of adding the mechanic of when the player hits the bottom of a block a coin instantiates directly above the block, waits for a second or two, then destroys itself and adds the value of that coin to the score.

With this script, everything is working besides the coroutine destroying the instantiated gameObject.

```
   using UnityEngine;
   using System.Collections;

public class BrickBlock : MonoBehaviour
{

    public GameObject CoinPrefab;
    public GameObject spawnPoint;
    public int CoinCount = 1;

    IEnumerator OnTriggerEnter2D()
    {
            if (CoinCount != 0)
            {
                Instantiate(CoinPrefab, spawnPoint.transform.position, spawnPoint.transform.rotation);
                yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

                Destroy(CoinPrefab);
                CoinCount--;
                ScoreManager.score += Coin.CoinValue;


            }

            if (CoinCount == 0)
            {
                print("Bitch you're breaking me!");

            }
        }
    }
```

I recieve an error "Destroying assets is not permitted to avoid data loss.
If you really want to remove an asset use DestroyImmediate (theObject, true);
UnityEngine.Object:Destroy(Object)
c__Iterator0:MoveNext() (at Assets/Scripts/BrickBlock.cs:18)"  but doing this simply destroys my prefab all together.

In the past, numerous of my questions have received thumbs down with little to no explanation why. If my question does not meet the standards of this forum or fails to provide enough information Please inform me. My problem may seem premature to some of you, but I am truly unable to solve this problem with my current frame of view. Your help is much appreciated.... Thank you:)

Comment: I personally think you deserve downvote for this question. It appears you gave zero own effort in finding the solution - the copied error message looks like the answer: either use `DestroyImmediate` or dont destroy the asset (but the *instance* of it). Cannot confirm either is correct answer right now, so I am leaving the downvotes for others if they seem fit.

Answer (score 3):

A small concept, often not clear to the people.

Man your `CoinPrefab` is only a public reference (a blueprint) of an object, you can create a new object through this, but cannot pick that new object directly through this public reference.

What are you doing which is wrong,

- You are instantiating an object using `CoinPrefab` but didn't assign to any variable.
- You are destroying `CoinPrefab` which is actually never created.

What you should do,

- Instantiate object and assign that in any new variable so you can keep the record.
- Destroy with that new reference.

  ```
  ........
  GameObject coin = Instantiate(CoinPrefab, spawnPoint.transform.position, spawnPoint.transform.rotation) as GameObject;
  yield return new WaitForSeconds(2);

  Destroy(coin);
  ..........
  ```

Comment: Thank you! This makes sense. The only thing that I had to do is change GameObject coin = ....  to Object coin = ..... Thank you once again!

Comment: With type casting. Check the edits

Comment: Did my tip work?